# Group_by function with shapiro.test() not working in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm using shapiro.test() to analyze the normality of two groups in R. I'm using the code below:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  shapiro.test(as.numeric(Outcome))
```

data is my dataframe uploaded through readcsv, Condition is a factor with variables "Y" and "N", and Outcome is a continuous variable. When I run this, I get the following error:

Error in shapiro.test(., as.numeric(Outcome)) :
unused argument (as.numeric(Outcome))

I've tried using "data$Outcome", but still nothing works. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you need to use `summarise/reframe` to do your shapiro test

Answer (score 0):

The rstatix package has a 'pipe-friendly' version of [Shapiro-Wilk's test](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/shapiro_test.html) that might be a potential solution, e.g. using the palmerpenguins dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(rstatix)

penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(species == "Gentoo") %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  shapiro_test(bill_depth_mm, bill_length_mm)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   sex    variable       statistic       p
#>   <fct>  <chr>              <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 female bill_depth_mm      0.986 0.736  
#> 2 female bill_length_mm     0.989 0.895  
#> 3 male   bill_depth_mm      0.980 0.401  
#> 4 male   bill_length_mm     0.940 0.00511

# Or you can use reframe() if you want to tweak the output a bit
penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(species == "Gentoo") %>%
  reframe(bill_depth = shapiro_test(bill_depth_mm),
          bill_length_pvalue = shapiro_test(bill_length_mm)$p.value,
          .by = sex)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   sex    bill_depth$variable $statistic $p.value bill_length_pvalue
#>   <fct>  <chr>                    <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1 female bill_depth_mm            0.986    0.736            0.895  
#> 2 male   bill_depth_mm            0.980    0.401            0.00511

# plot the variables to check
# approx normal distribution
penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(species == "Gentoo") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = bill_depth_mm, fill = sex)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

```r
# males have a long tail / non-normal distribution
# (in agreement with the shapiro test results)

penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(species == "Gentoo") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = bill_length_mm, fill = sex)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>